# Removing repeating values from sql

Tags: sql, view

I have a question for my homework in class that goes as such:
The Professor wants to review information about questions on quizzes that appear to be difficult.

Create a view named HardQuizzes that contains the quiz number, quiz date, average score, question id, number of students who chose A, number of students who chose B, number of students who chose C, and number of students who chose D for each question on a quiz where the average score is less than 15. Verify that the view has been created correctly. Confirm the change.

And I think I came up with a way to get the answer with this:

```
CREATE VIEW HardQuizzes 
AS
    SELECT DISTINCT
        QQ.QuizNum,
        QQ.QuizDate,
        AvgScore, 
        NumChoseA, 
        NumChoseB,
        NumChoseC, 
        NumChoseD 
    FROM
        QuizQuestions QQ, 
        Quizzes Q 
    WHERE
        QQ.QuizNum = Q.QuizNum 
        AND AvgScore < 15
```

But when I do this it creates the view but so many of the values repeat and I cant figure out a way to stop them repeating. Is there a way do that?

[This is a screenshot of the view when I make it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVYZ0.png)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: I don't see any duplicate rows in your data in the screenshot - `DISTINCT` appears to be working. So what is your question, then, really??

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an assignment, hoping to just nudge you in the right direction -

What other data is available in the original tables that you can investigate?

Are there multiple classes taking each of these quizzes?

If there are multiple classes, would the intent of the question lead you to believe the records should be combined?

- If that's the case this could be accomplished with GROUP BY and aggregation functions over the NumChose columns.